# How to save the job results to the same folder as the job.sh file in cluster?

Tags: linux, bash, directory, sh, cluster-computing

To run a job in cluster, I need to submit a `job.sh` file, in which one of the parameters to set is the working directory `#$ -wd /path/to/save/the/result/`.

I have different `job.sh` files in different directories. All the `job.sh` are almost identical except I have to change the `/path/to/save/the/result/` to the corresponding directory, where each `job.sh` locates, so that the results will be saved in the same place as each `job.sh`.

As I have many job.sh files at different directories, it takes a lot of time to specifically define the `/path/to/save/the/result/`.

If I use `#$ -cwd`, the results will be saved where I launch the `job.sh` file, which is also not good. I have to use `cd /path/to/save/the/result/`, then `qsub job.sh` every time.

So is there a way that I can replace the different `/path/to/save/the/result/` with a same variable, which always points to the directory of the `job.sh` file?

An example of my current job.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -l h_rt=00:30:0
#$ -l mem=2G
#$ -l tmpfs=15G
#$ -N md_0_1
#$ -pe mpi 4
#$ -wd /path/to/save/the/result/

module unload compilers mpi
module load compilers/intel/2015/update2
module load mpi/intel/2015/update3/intel
module load gromacs/5.1.1/intel-2015-update2

gmx mdrun -deffnm md_0_1
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically use `current_directory="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"` which gets the directory of the location the script is.

Then you can write to `$current_directory/output.csv` or whatever your output file should be.

Comment: I tried `#$ -wd "$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"` but got this error message: `error: can't chdir to $( cd $( dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} ) && pwd ): No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dirname $0` to get the location of the script `job.sh`.

EDIT:

For OP's `job.sh`, one can group the command and write the output to logfile, something like this:

```
$ cat job.sh
#!/bin/bash

scriptDir="$(dirname $0)"

# Group the commands and send the output to a logfile
{
module unload compilers mpi
module load compilers/intel/2015/update2
module load mpi/intel/2015/update3/intel
module load gromacs/5.1.1/intel-2015-update2

gmx mdrun -deffnm md_0_1
} &>> "${scriptDir}/logfilename.log"
```

Run the script:

```
$ qsub /path/to/job.sh
```

This should create `${scriptDir}/logfilename.log` as long as the path is accessible to the cluster.

Comment: thanks, sorry, could you please tell me exactly how to change my job.sh file?

Comment: See my updated answer. You can write to a logfile under scriptDir.

Comment: Do you mean, before running `qsub job.sh`, I need to run your code in the putty command line?

Comment: No, I meant, you put the `$scriptDir` and `logfile` lines inside your `job.sh`, then do `qsub /path/to/job.sh`.

Comment: Sorry I am still confused, could you please show me the entire modified `job.sh` file? I have the example shown. How to deal with `#$ -wd /path/to/save/the/result/`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164012/discussion-between-lanselibai-and-iamauser).